# Can different RDBMS have impact on ORM performance test results?

Tags: .net, performance, orm

I made some ORM framework performance tests on MSSQL (EF,NH in comparrison with pure ADO.NET approach). EF, NH and ADO.NET should use same ADO.NET provider for DB. My question is, if its possible that EF could have some advantage over NH on MSSQL.

Therefore I'm asking if it is possible that using different DB (MySql for example), could have **relevant** impact on ORM performance test results.

(by relevant I mean that ORM X has improved its performance by x% and ORM Y by y% where x != y :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely. For example, MySQL does not have hash and merge joins. Certain query patterns will suffer greatly there.

The notion that the RDBMS used does not matter is strange to me. Different databases have very non-uniform performance characteristics. Performance very much varies with workload.

If you want to exclude the RDBMS as much as possible from your tests you have to carefully make sure that you are not testing any RDBMS-specific performance features by accident. This is very hard.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Even different settings on the same RDBMS can lead to different test results.